# MySQL - decrement int value, delete row if int reaches 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to find a query that does the exact opposite of this:

```
INSERT INTO WordsTable (word, counter) 
VALUES('$word', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = counter + 1
```

(This SQL is fine. "word" is set to unique and everything)

So, basically, decrement the counter, if the counter reaches 0, delete the whole row. I'm thinking it might look like this but I've no clue if this is valid syntax:

```
UPDATE WordsTable
SET counter = counter - 1
WHERE id='$deleteThisWord'
IF (occ = 0) THEN
(
    DELETE *
    FROM WordsTable
    WHERE id='$deleteThisWord'
)
```

Is there a nice clean way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it as two queries:

```
DELETE
FROM WordsTable
WHERE id='$deleteThisWord' AND counter = 1;

UPDATE WordsTable
SET counter = counter - 1
WHERE id = '$deleteThisWord'
```

Comment: Is it not possible at all to do it single query? I do not know much about SQL

Comment: No, there's no way to combine DELETE and UPDATE.

Comment: You can combine `INSERT` and `UPDATE` by using the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause, but that's it.